# Removing subquery of select statement used multiple times to optimize the performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a following query,
this query uses a subquery in the select clause multiple times as

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(9,4)) 
          FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
          WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
          AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4)
```

I want to remove this subquery. I tried using group by CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(9,4)), but now it ask to include other columns as well in the group by cluase.

Any help is really appreciated.

The main query is

```
DECLARE @Region int=10006

SELECT 
    st.strRegion,
    st.intStore,
    st.strStoreName,
    tblSticker.intStickerNo ,
    tblSticker.strTeamNo AS strTeam ,
    tblSticker.dtmFixtureStartDate AS dtmStartDate ,
    tblSticker.intAreaNo ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblSticker.strMiscText , 8 , 30 ) AS strSection ,
    tblDetail.intLineNum ,
    tblDetail.strBarcode ,
    tblDetail.intBarcodeLength ,
    tblDetail.intBarcodeType ,
    tblDetail.strBarcodeEntrySw AS strKeyBarcode ,
    tblDetail.fltPrice AS fltPrice ,
    tblDetail.fltQty AS fltQty ,
    tblDetail.strPTCCode4 AS strKeyPrice ,
    tblDetail.strPTCCode5 AS strKeyQty ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 1 , 1 ) AS strNOF ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strClientText , 1 , 30 ) AS strDesc ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 12 , 4 ) AS strSubTeam ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 16 , 25 ) AS strSubTeamDesc ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strClientText , 34 , 3 ) AS strSubDept ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strClientText , 37 , 3 ) AS strClass ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strClientText , 40 , 3 ) AS strSubClass ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 41 , 7 ) AS strCostFactor ,
    SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 41 , 1 ) AS strPerishableFlag ,
    tblSubTeam.blnBreakoutCost,
    fltPriceLb = tblDetail.fltClientMisc1,
    fltCostLb = CASE 
      WHEN tblDetail.decCost > 0
          THEN tblDetail.decCost
          ELSE tblDetail.fltClientMisc1 *
        ( SELECT DISTINCT CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(6,4)) 
          FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
          WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
          AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4) 
        )
          END,
      strVendor = CASE WHEN tblDetail.strVendor IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE tblDetail.strVendor END,

    fltWeightSouth = CASE 
      WHEN tblDetail.fltClientMisc1 > 0
        THEN (tblDetail.fltPrice / tblDetail.fltClientMisc1)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,49,1) <> 'R' 
      AND  tblDetail.fltClientMisc1 = 0 
      THEN cast(SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText,43,6) as float)
        ELSE 0 
      END,

    fltCostSouth = ISNULL(CASE 
      WHEN SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,50,1) = 'C' 
      THEN (tblDetail.fltPrice ) 
            ELSE
        -- To calculate cost for Subteam 3100 in the south region -  Thomas - 2/19/2008
                CASE 
        WHEN (SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4) = '3100') 
        AND (Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,1,1) <> 'N')
                THEN fltprice  * 
          ( SELECT DISTINCT CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(6,4)) 
            FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
            AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText, 12, 4)
          )
                ELSE CASE 
          WHEN tblDetail.fltClientMisc1 > 0 and tblDetail.decCost > 0
                  -- modified by TA to remedy Extended Retail for weighted items
                  THEN (tblDetail.fltPrice / tblDetail.fltClientMisc1) * tblDetail.decCost 
                  ELSE CASE
                        WHEN (Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,1,1) = 'N')  
            Or   (tblDetail.strBarcode = '00000000000000')
                        THEN CASE 
              WHEN (fltprice = 0 and tblDetail.decCost > 0) 
              THEN CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText,43,6) <> '' 
                THEN CASE 
                  WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText,43,6) as float) > 0 
                                    THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText,43,6) as float)*tblDetail.decCost 
                                    ELSE fltTotalUnits*tblDetail.decCost
                                  END
                                ELSE 0 * tblDetail.decCost
                                END
                            ELSE CASE 
                WHEN (Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7)) = ''
                                THEN fltprice * 0 
                                ELSE fltprice  * Cast(Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7) as decimal(6,4)) 
                                END
                            END
                        ELSE CASE 
              WHEN (fltprice > 0 and tblDetail.decCost = 0) 
                            THEN  fltprice  * 
                ( SELECT DISTINCT CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(6,4)) 
                  FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
                  WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
                  AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4)
                )
                            ELSE CASE 
                WHEN (fltprice = 0 and tblDetail.decCost > 0) 
                THEN CASE 
                  WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText,43,6) as float) > 0 
                                    THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText,43,6) as float) * tblDetail.decCost 
                                    ELSE tblDetail.decCost 
                                    END
                              ELSE tblDetail.decCost 
                                END
                            END
            END
          END
        END
      END,0),

  fltItemCost = ISNULL(CASE
    WHEN ((((Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7) = '00.0000') 
            or (tblDetail.fltClientMisc1 = 0)) 
            or (tblDetail.decCost = 0)) 
            and Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,1,1) <> 'N') 
        THEN CASE 
      WHEN (fltprice > 0 and tblDetail.decCost = 0) 
            THEN  fltprice * 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(9,4)) 
          FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
          WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
          AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4)
        )   
            ELSE CASE 
        WHEN (fltprice = 0 and tblDetail.decCost > 0) 
                THEN tblDetail.decCost
                ELSE CASE 
          WHEN  (Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7)) = ''
                    THEN  fltprice * 0
                    ELSE fltprice  * Cast(Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7) as decimal(9,4)) 
                    END
                END
            END
            ELSE CASE 
        WHEN (Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,1,1) = 'N') 
        Or   (tblDetail.strBarcode = '00000000000000')
                THEN fltprice * Cast(Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7) as decimal(9,4)) 
                ELSE CASE 
          WHEN (fltprice > 0 and tblDetail.decCost = 0) 
                    THEN  fltprice  * 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(9,4)) 
              FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
              WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
              AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4)
            )   
                    ELSE CASE 
            WHEN (Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7)) = ''
                        THEN fltprice * 0
                        ELSE fltprice  * Cast(Substring(tblDetail.strMiscText,41,7) as decimal(9,4)) 
                      END
                    END
                END
      END, 0),
      strWeight = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strClientText, 43, 6)

FROM
tblSticker WITH ( NOLOCK )
INNER JOIN tblDetail WITH ( NOLOCK )
ON tblSticker.intStore = tblDetail.intStore
   AND tblSticker.intStickerNo = tblDetail.intStickerNo
   AND tblSticker.dtmStickerDate = tblDetail.dtmStickerDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblsubteam
ON tblDetail.intStore = tblSubTeam.intStore
   AND SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 12 , 4 ) = tblSubTeam.strSubTeam
inner join tblStore st on st.intStore=tblDetail.intStore
--fix add join to store.  Kevin 2/8/07

-- AND SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 12 , 4 ) = tblSubTeam.strSubTeam
--fix fix move join to store outside of compound conditional.  Eddie 9/2/11
WHERE
   ((@Region is not null and st.intRegion=@Region) or @Region is  null)
    AND st.intStore < 90000
    AND ( tblSticker.intStickerNo NOT BETWEEN 334717100
          AND 334717299 )
    AND tblSticker.strRescanSW = 'N'
    AND ( tblSticker.strEmptyStatus = ' '
          OR tblSticker.strEmptyStatus = '*' )
ORDER BY st.strStoreName,
    tblSticker.intStickerNo ,
    tblDetail.intLineNum
```

Answer (score 4):

You can move your query to an [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), this ensures that it is only executed once.

I think your example would become something like:

```
FROM    tblSticker WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN tblDetail WITH ( NOLOCK )
            ON tblSticker.intStore = tblDetail.intStore
            AND tblSticker.intStickerNo = tblDetail.intStickerNo
            AND tblSticker.dtmStickerDate = tblDetail.dtmStickerDate
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblsubteam
            ON tblDetail.intStore = tblSubTeam.intStore
            AND SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 12 , 4 ) = tblSubTeam.strSubTeam
        INNER JOIN tblStore st 
            ON st.intStore=tblDetail.intStore
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  DeCostFactor = CAST(decCostFactor AS DECIMAL(9,4)) 
            FROM    tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE   intstore = st.intStore 
            AND     strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4)
        ) dcf
```

Then instead of your subquery you can simply refer to `dcf.DeCostFactor`.

As a generic test I have used the following, that simply executes a correlated subquery 4 times, compared to a single APPLY

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

WITH T AS
(   SELECT  A = Number, B = Number + 1
    FROM    Master..spt_values
    WHERE   Type = 'P'
)
SELECT  T.A,
        T.B,
        SubQuery = (SELECT T2.B FROM T T2 WHERE T2.A = T.B),
        SubQuery2 = (SELECT T2.B FROM T T2 WHERE T2.A = T.B),
        SubQuery3 = (SELECT T2.B FROM T T2 WHERE T2.A = T.B),
        SubQuery4 =  (SELECT T2.B FROM T T2 WHERE T2.A = T.B)
FROM    T;


-- USING OUTER APPLY
WITH T AS
(   SELECT  A = Number, B = Number + 1
    FROM    Master..spt_values
    WHERE   Type = 'P'
)
SELECT  T.A,
        T.B,
        SubQuery = SubQuery.B,
        SubQuery2 = SubQuery.B,
        SubQuery3 = SubQuery.B,
        SubQuery4 = SubQuery.B
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  T2.B
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.A = T.B
        ) SubQuery;
```

THE IO Statistics speak for themselves:

**Multiple Subqueries**

```
Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 8193, logical reads 24625, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

**OUTER APPLY**

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 2, logical reads 18, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

---

**EDIT**

I don't think you need the subqueries at all, you have already joined to the table `tblSubteam` on the same criteria:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblsubteam
    ON tblDetail.intStore = tblSubTeam.intStore
    AND SUBSTRING ( tblDetail.strMiscText , 12 , 4 ) = tblSubTeam.strSubTeam
```

Why can't you just use `tblsubteam.DeCostFactor` instead of the subquery?

Comment: just using tblsubteam.DeCostFactor resulted in repeated dulicate values for DeCostFactor

Comment: Then the join will still be causing duplicates, they will just be hidden by the fact you are not selecting that column.

Answer (score 1):

You have this as a subquery in the `select` clause.  Hence, it must return one value.  Hence, you can replace it with:

```
    ( SELECT top 1 CAST(decCostFactor as decimal(6,4)) 
      FROM tblsubteam WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE intstore = st.intStore 
      AND strsubteam = SUBSTRING(tblDetail.strMiscText,12,4) 
    )
```

SQL Server is pretty good about optimization.  However, the `distinct` might pose a problem.  Removing the distinct and just taking an arbitrary value might improve the optimization.

The way to check, though, is by looking at the execution plan.

The performance would probably be improved by having an index on `tblsubteam(instore, strsubteam, decCostFactor)`.